# Quantify the correlation of arbitrarily sized collection of time series

Tags: time-series, correlation, estimation, prediction, cross-correlation

Given a set $N$ of continuous time series of equal lengths, is there a metric for how well they all correlate with each other?

**I've considered** a metric; average Pearson, $\hat{P}$, given by calculating the Pearson coefficient $P$ between all pairs $\{(T_i,T_j)\in N\}$ of time series and taking the average:

$$ \hat{P}(N) = {\sum_{i=1}^{\vert N\vert} \sum_{j=1}^{\vert N\vert} P(T_i,T_j) \over{\vert N\vert}}$$

Can I use that to imply that we can (better) estimate/predict the value of a time-series $T_i$ at time-step $t$ denoted $T_i(t)$, given the value for all other time-series $\{T_j(t) \in N | j \neq i \}$? (especially

> If necessary, assume you we know all values of all time-series except the value of $T_i(t)$.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? To what use would you put such a correlation measure?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen For example: assume people's money use over a month as the time series. Perhaps the people in group $A$ have a *higher $\hat P$ value* than the people in group $B$. This could perhaps indicate how complicated a statistical model has to be to accurately model that data.